# MySQL - нет формата SQL при экспорте таблицы

Tags: mysql

**Версия сервера** - 5.6.33

**Версия PMA** - 4.8.4

При экспорте таблицы отсутствует выбор SQL-формата:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что мне делать? Обновлять свой WAMP/XAMPP/LAMP не хочется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашелся на enSO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801142/why-has-the-latest-phpmyadmin-dropped-sql-as-export-format/53801915#53801915

Ссылки с подробностями ошибки можно найти там же (мне просто лень)))

1. Открываем файл (начальный путь для Wamp64) wamp64\apps\phpmyadminX.X.X\libraries\classes\Display\Export.php
2. Находим строку `/* Scan for plugins */`
3. Добавляем после нее (перед объявлением `$exportList`):

   ```
   // Export a single table

   if (isset($_GET['single_table'])) {

       $GLOBALS['single_table'] = $_GET['single_table'];

   }
   ```
4. Сохраняем файл и перезапускаем сервер.

После этого при выгрузке формат SQL появится в списке доступных